# select2 css takes too long to load

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, search, jquery-select2

I'm using the nice [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) for multiple select fields on my web applications search page. One can search for people by company/industry/school. Because there are hundreds of searchable values for each, it is taking time for the correct select2 css to load (about 1 second). The old ugly select fields can be seen in a flicker before the pretty select2 fields display. Attached are two screenshots that show the transition.

Here is my view code:

```
        <%= form_tag('', :method => :get) do %>
          <div class="row-fluid">  
            <div class="span4">
              <label>What industries have they worked in?</label>
                <%= select_tag "industry_ids", options_for_select((@visible_industries), params[:industry_ids]), { :placeholder => "Type to search...", :multiple => true, :id => "e3", :onchange => 'this.form.submit();' } %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :&, params[:industry_ids] %>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <label>What companies have they worked at?</label>
                <%= select_tag "company_ids", options_for_select((@visible_companies), params[:company_ids]), { :placeholder => "Type to search...", :multiple => true, :onchange => 'this.form.submit();' } %>
                  <%= hidden_field_tag :&, params[:company_ids] %>           
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
              <label>Where did they go to school?</label>
              <%= select_tag "school_ids", options_for_select((@visible_schools), params[:school_ids]), { :placeholder => "Type to search...", :multiple => true, :onchange => 'this.form.submit();' } %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :&, params[:school_ids] %>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And controller code:

```
  def people
    @current_user = current_user

    @visible_positions = Position.where{ is_visible.eq('true') }
    @visible_educations = Education.where{ is_visible.eq('true') }

    @visible_companies = @visible_positions.order("LOWER(company)").all.map { |p| [ p.company, p.company ] }.uniq
    @visible_industries = @visible_positions.order("LOWER(industry)").all.map { |p| [ p.industry, p.industry ] }.uniq
    @visible_schools = @visible_educations.order("LOWER(school)").all.map { |e| [ e.school, e.school ] }.uniq

    @c = @visible_positions.where{company.in(my{params[:company_ids]})}.map(&:user_id)
    @i = @visible_positions.where{industry.in(my{params[:industry_ids]})}.map(&:user_id)
    @s = @visible_educations.where{school.in(my{params[:school_ids]})}.map(&:user_id)

    unless @c.empty? && @i.empty? && @s.empty?
      @users = User.find([@c,@i,@s].reject(&:empty?).reduce(:&))
    end

  end
```

Finally, I have this javascript in my assets directory (in addition to the select2 css):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1
  });
});
```

What can I do to prevent this flicker from happening? Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's the way the page get rendered. My suggestion would be to hide the selects till the page is fully loaded (and select2 applied).

Comment: How exactly would I hide them until the page is fully loaded? Thanks!

Comment: In the stylesheet, add a `input {display:none;}` rule to hide them (although `visibility:hidden` might be better). Then with jQuery override that rule `$('input').css("display","inline");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'll post my comment as an answer since it solved your issue.*

My suggestion would be to hide the selects till the page is fully loaded (and select2 applied).

In the stylesheet, add a `input {display:none;}` rule to hide them (although `visibility:hidden` might be better). Then with jQuery override that rule `$('input').css("display","inline");`.